# Azure Timer Function API Call to Azure SQL

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I am VERY new to Azure and Azure functions, so be gentle.  :-)

I am trying to write an Azure timer function (using Python) that will take the results returned from an API call and insert the results into a table in Azure SQL.

I am virtually clueless.  If someone would be willing to handhold me through the process, it would be MOST appreciated.

I have the API call already written, so that part is done.  What I totally don't get is how to get the results from what is returned into Azure SQL.

The result set I am returning is in the form of a Pandas dataframe.

Again, any and all assistance would be AMAZING!

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that writes a panda data structure to and SQL Table:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
# insert data from csv file into dataframe.
# working directory for csv file: type "pwd" in Azure Data Studio or Linux
# working directory in Windows c:\users\username
df = pd.read_csv("c:\\user\\username\department.csv")
# Some other example server values are
# server = 'localhost\sqlexpress' # for a named instance
# server = 'myserver,port' # to specify an alternate port
server = 'yourservername' 
database = 'AdventureWorks' 
username = 'username' 
password = 'yourpassword' 
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
# Insert Dataframe into SQL Server:
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO HumanResources.DepartmentTest (DepartmentID,Name,GroupName) values(?,?,?)", row.DepartmentID, row.Name, row.GroupName)
cnxn.commit()
cursor.close()
```

To make it work for your case you need to:

- replace the read from csv file with your function call
- Change the insert statement to match the structure of your SQL Table.

For more details see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/data-exploration/python-dataframe-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Thank you!!!!  I am going to give this a go and will reply.  The thing I was totally missing (and I guess I should have gotten since this is how I have done this when doing inserts into local db's) was the cursor and iterrows piece.

You have no idea how much I appreciate this!!!!

Comment: I keep running into an error I can't seem to get past.  I set all the data types and ensured all the column names are the same, but I keep getting the following error.

ProgrammingError: ('42S22', "[42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'propertyid'. (207) (SQLExecDirectW); [42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")

Thoughts?

Comment: Since it is and id field, it could be that you are trying to insert data into an auto increment property. It could also be a problem with case sensitivity. Is the field name "Propertyid"